# JQUERY - Waiting for window.location.href to Complete

Tags: jquery

I am using the following line to kick off main.php which loads an iframe:

```
 window.location.href = '/main.php?token='+obj.token;
```

I need to wait for the iframe to complete loading so the $_GET token can be obtained.

After this I want to run the below line to remove the token from the command line:

```
  window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

At the moment pushState always fires to quickly and then token is lost. 
Is there a way to delay this until the iframe is completely loaded?
Don't want to use a timer as it might not work sometimes.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind to the `ready` event of the iframe like so:

```
$("#frametest").ready(function(){alert("loaded");});
```

where `frametest` is the id of your iframe.

Here is a jsfiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/fQB2H/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe can use onload in body section like this:

> BODY onload="on_load();">

Then at the bottom of the page create some js code what will communicate with your main window or just run some code when page is loaded.

> ```
>   <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
>
>   function on_load() {
>
>       parent.functionName();
>
>   }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can catch the `load` event,  that is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded, in this way:

```
$('#myiframe').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```